# How to apply Format object to index values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Question:   I have a data frame with column names with respective values. But when i apply format object to column headings, they are not responding.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

root = "C:\Users\543904\Desktop\New folder\"

dict = {'name':["aparna", "pankaj"],
        'degree': ["MBA", "BCA"],
        'score':[90, 40]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(root + 'output', engine = "xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df', index = False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['df']

Format_Object = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
Format_Object.set_bold()
Format_Object.set_align('center')
Format_Object.set_align('top')
Format_Object.set_border(1)
Format_Object.set_bg_color('#0ef0ce')

worksheet.set_row(0, 20, Format_Object)

writer.save()
```

expected:

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnEzr.jpg)

Actual:

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2g0B.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the XlsxWriter docs on [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers):

> Pandas writes the dataframe header with a default cell format. Since it is a cell format it cannot be overridden using `set_row()`. If you wish to use your own format for the headings then the best approach is to turn off the automatic header from Pandas and write your own. For example:

```
# Turn off the default header and skip one row to allow us to insert a
# user defined header.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @jmcnamara. It is working perfectly.